# Вылетает приложение из-за разрешения изображения

Tags: java, android

При запуске приложения в imageview установлена картинка низкого разрешения (1024х658). Кнопкой в это imageview должна установиться другая картинка с высоким разрешением (3840х2160), но вместо этого приложение вылетает. Подскажите, как можно исправить проблему.

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imV.setImageResource(R.drawable.nos2);
            }
        });

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/nos1" />
```

2019-07-24 23:17:23.276 9899-9899/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.animals, PID: 9899
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(294000000bytes) bitmap.
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
        at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19123)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:2023)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19126)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:785)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:643)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:649)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:757)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2980)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2794)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2347)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: Что говорят логи, текст ошибки/исключения?

Comment: ``RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(294000000bytes) bitmap`` - нужно уменьшить количество байт, которое занимает изображение.

Comment: уменьшить качество картинки, верно? это единственный выход?

Comment: картинка от которой вылетает < 2 590 000 байт

Comment: переместите картинку в папку drawable-xxhdpi, должно помочь

Comment: нет, так приложение вовсе не запускается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В зависимости от задачи решений несколько.

Если вам просто надо другую картинку отобразить, то можно попробовать использовать библиотеку `Glide`.

Также нужно иметь в виду, что если картинка находится в папке `res/drawable`, то она может автоматически увеличиваться на девайсах с большой плотностью пикселей на экранах. Вплоть до 4 раз. Что может как раз приводить к вылету. Чтобы этого избежать можно или сделать несколько версий картинки в разных разрешениях и разложить их в соответствующие папки или переместить исходную картинку в папку `res/drawable-nodpi` - так она не будет автоматически увеличиваться.

Если же вам надо отображать картинку неизвестного, но обязательно очень большого размера, то можно заморочиться и отображать только часть оной (что в экран влезает), обрезав лишнее. Или вручную же её уменьшить до размеров экрана. Но, вроде, `Glide` как раз это и может автоматически делать.

---

Также не стоит использовать `app:srcCompat` если вы не уверены, что оно вам точно нужно. Вроде как оно для обратной совместимости отрисовки векторных картинок на старых девайсах. Лучше использовать стандартный `android:src`

Comment: Спасибо большое! В моём случае помогло простое перемещение картинки в res/drawable-nodpi